# Как сделать движение между векторами

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Как сделать движение между 2-я векторами. Есть **Vector3.MoveTowards(from,to,step)**, но как сделать задержку?

Comment: Что значит " сделать задержку"?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker то-есть сделать так чтобы при смене шага была задержка, а то происходит всё моментально и не видно перелёта с одной позиции в другую

Comment: Может вызвать метод через Invoke?
void MoveObject(){
...
}

Invoke("MoveObject", 0.5f);

Или IEnumerator.

Comment: Invoke тут вообще не к месту, нужно интерполировать step, либо (в идеале) использовать tween engine.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker можно с этого места по подробнее?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker огромное спасибо) использовал DOTween

Comment: Тогда оформите ответ - чтобы другие люди с такой же проблемой могли увидеть его

Answer (score 0):

Для этого используем библиотеку DOTween v2. Библиотека 
даём новые функции к существующим классам и создаёт новые(Подробнее в документации).
При инициализации используем:

```
DOTween.Init();
```

Чтобы переместится между точками используем:

```
transform.DOMove(Vector 3 to,float time);
```